# How to persist XMLGregorianCalendar with JPA?

Tags: hibernate, soap, cxf

This is what I have:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
@Column(name = "expiry-date", nullable = false)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar expiryDate;
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XMLGregorianCalendar` is not supported by JPA, you could use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` (explained [here](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Temporal)).

Maybe you could take a look at the project [Hyperjaxb3](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home) (provides relational persistence for JAXB objects).
[Here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Making+schema-derived+classes+ready+for+JPA) it's explained how to deal with temporal properties:

> Temporal properties (typed xsd:dateTime, xsd:date, xsd:time and so on)
>   will be mapped as temporal JPA properties. Hyperjaxb3 will choose
>   temporal type as TIMESTAMP, DATE or TIME depending on the XML Schema
>   type of the temporal property. Temporal properties are typically
>   mapped onto XMLGregorianCalendar which is not supported by JPA - and
>   therefor must be wrapped:

```
<xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

---

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime;
@Transient
public XMLGregorianCalendar getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}
public void setDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    this.dateTime = value;
}
@Basic
@Column(name = "DATETIMEITEM")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getDateTimeItem() {
    return XmlAdapterUtils.unmarshall(XMLGregorianCalendarAsDateTime.class, this.getDateTime());
}

public void setDateTimeItem(Date target) {
    setDateTime(XmlAdapterUtils.marshall(XMLGregorianCalendarAsDateTime.class, target));
}
```

Another way would be to code your own solution, performing some transformations instead of trying to persist your JAXB object.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do that without using any additional framework. For example:

```
@Transient
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar expiryDate;

@Column(name = "expiry-Date", nullable = false)
public Calendar getExpiryDateToCalendar() {
    return new GregorianCalendar(expiryDate.getYear(), expiryDate.getMonth(), expiryDate.getDay());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. You should also pay attention for months in code as in XMLGregorianCalendar months define from 1 to 12, however in Calendar - from 0 to 11.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name="test_my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    @Transient
    protected String name;

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    @Transient
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar myXMLDate;

    @Transient
    private Calendar calendarDate;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "calendar_date")
    private Calendar getCalendarDate() {
        return new GregorianCalendar(myXMLDate.getYear(), myXMLDate.getMonth()-1, myXMLDate.getDay());
    }

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "my_str_name")
    public String getName() {
        return "My string";
    }

    //...setters here

    public MyEntity() {
    }
}
```